# Get SMS responses into a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, twilio

I have been been able to use Twilio and SharePoint to send SMS messages. We would like to go to the next stage and create a question/response system and receive those SMS messages from our customers and add them to a SharePoint list, therefore kicking off workflows based on the customer's SMS response.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I will leave this up to Sharepoint side to see what API's are exposed to allow writing data. This can be done with Google Sheets and different DB platforms like Airtable via their exposed / documented REST API's.

Comment: SharePoint does REST, but I guess I'm not sure how to get it to "GET" a customer's response via SMS. Thanks for the reply, though!

Answer (score 0):

Inbound SMS are sent to your Twilio number which you can then define a webhook for. The webhook (the URL Twilio will sent an HTTP Request to when a message is received) will contain the `Body` of the SMS message.

[TwiML™ for Programmable SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml)

[What is a Webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook)